# Using QGIS to obtain lat/long coordinates from large data with addresses

Tags: qgis, geocoding, address, nominatim, big-data

In QGIS, I have a requirement to obtain lat/long coordinates for an US address, and I'm looking for low-cost alternatives to the Google Maps API. I have a (very) large dataset; right now I'm looking at ~6 million US addresses. I do not need any maps or images, just coordinates.

Can QGIS accomplish this? If so, how?

EDIT: Added the fact the addresses I need to geocode are located in the USA.

Comment: How accurate do you need the coordinates? Would it be OK to locate the addresses to postcodes area, census tracts, cities or do you really need to locate it down to the house?

Comment: At the risk of showing my ignorance, I don't know how to answer your question but I will ultimately need down to the census block level. The Census Bureau Geocoder is not able to geocode all of my addresses, especially PO Boxes. That is why I'm looking for other Geocoding Services.

Comment: IMHO, there is a better option exists specifically for the USA, i.e. ["Census geocoder"](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/geography/technical-documentation/complete-technical-documentation/census-geocoder.html). One can also find a corresponding Python package [`censusgeocode`](https://github.com/fitnr/censusgeocode). However, there is a limit of 10,000 rows of the input file (perhaps not for requests). Solution: divide your initial CSV-file into 600 CSV-files, and after merge back the results. Do not forget about a unique ID for each record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a free Geocoding service included in newer QGIS versions: [Batch Nominatim Geocoder](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisbatchnominatimgeocoder). However, heavy use of the service is agains the [Nominatim Usage Policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/). The rule of an absolute maximum of 1 request per second e.g. would mean you need at least ca. 3 months running the service 24/7 to geocode all 6 million addresses.

Geocoding needs a lot of resources/computing power and free services thus almost always are limited in capacity.

So for (very) large datasets, there is probably no other way then to either

- use another (commercial) service (see here a [list of alternatives](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Alternatives_.2F_Third-party_providers)) and pay a fee (or distribute you task to different services, if that fits your needs and quality requirements and respects the rules of the services included) or
- install your own Nominatim instance (best, but most complex option)

> **Alternatives / Third-party providers**
>
> For slightly larger requirements you may be able to use commercial
> third-party providers. Some are listed on the Nominatim wiki page.
>
> If your requirements are even larger you can install your own instance
> of Nominatim.
>
> https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/

Comment: Babel, thank you for your reply. It is most helpful.